# Google Sheets - SUM the max value in rows where there is a unique value in a group

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to have a cell sum the maximum values in column C for each unique instance of A where B matches cell A1 on my sheet.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pie | Apple | 3 |
| Tart | Apple | 2 |
| Pie | Cherry | 1 |
| Pie | Apple | 5 |
| Tart | Cherry | 4 |
| Pie | Cherry | 4 |
| Pie | Cherry | 6 |

So for this data above, when I have "Apple" in A1 on my sheet it would calculate 7 (based on 5+2) or when I have "Cherry" in A1 it would calculate 7 (based on 6+1).

I have tried QUERY but I'm thinking I need an arrayformula or vlookup combined with a query, but am struggling to identify the right method.

Can anyone point me down the right path?

Comment: Hi. Cherry would be 7 (6+1); sure you don't mean 10 (6+4)?

Answer (score 1):

There might be several ways to approach your problem. Try this formula:

`=sum(query(A3:C9,"select A, max(C) where B contains '"&A1&"' group by A label max(C) ''"))`

Returns the maximum value groups by Column A, and sums the result.

Comment: That worked great!  Thank you so much for the quick help.

Comment: If you thought this was a “good” answer, then you might consider voting for &/or “accepting” it.